# SQL - Display the change in a grouped value from one group to another one (depending on time)

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I created an SQL view which groups by 1 minute intervals:

```
CREATE VIEW `summary` AS
    WITH shops AS (    
        SELECT    
            shop,
            timestamp DIV 1000000 DIV 60 AS timestamp,
            SUM(amount) AS sum_amount
        FROM 
            products
        GROUP BY timestamp DIV 1000000 DIV 60, shop
    )    

    SELECT * FROM shops
```

Now i want to also have a field which gives me the change in `sum_amount` from the previous grouped row / interval. "previous group" means the group which has the next lower timestamp.

I tried adding another `WITH` declaration and selecting from both subqueries:

```
    previous_group AS
    (    
        SELECT 
            s2.sum_amount AS previous_sum_amount
        FROM
            shops s1, shops s2
        WHERE
            s2.timestamp + (1000000 * 60) = s1.timestamp
    )

    SELECT
        shop,
        timestamp,
        sum_amount,
        sum_amount / previous_sum_amount AS change
    FROM
        shops, previous_group
```

However, this query runs forever. How can i achieve displaying the change in the `sum_amount` from one time interval to the next one?

Thank you.

EDIT:
Dropped the `previous_group` table and solved it with the `LAG` window function - thanks to Rick James.

```
SELECT
    shop,
    timestamp,
    sum_amount,
    sum_amount / LAG(sum_amount, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY shop ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS change
FROM
    shops, previous_group
```

Comment: You are not joining your 2 tables, shouldn't you be relating them in some way? Unless your previous_group query returns one row, you have a cartesian join

Comment: I joined them now, but the query is still runinng till the server closes it (25s)

Comment: I could reduce the issue to the `previous_group` subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `VIEW`, there is *no* need to use `WITH` and the second `SELECT`.  Simply do the first `SELECT`.

For the "change", don't bother with `WITH`, instead use `LAG`.

Comment: hey thanks, i could solve it with the window function. However, i do not understand how to achieve it by dropping the subquery since i want to divide by a group field, not a product field. EDIT: oh i guess i understand what you meant